# How tag stat works?

Tags: support, questions, tags

I want to know how this point count system works.
Is it updated daily or instantly?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Its updated daily, we used to cache it for 5-20 mins but were seeing some serious performance issues there.

The same cache is used to assign out tag badges

Comment: and how this point is being counted ?